# Are interned strings excepted from garbage collection in .NET?

Tags: c#, string, garbage-collection, string-interning

I am trying to reduce time it takes to do a Gen2 collection. My app creates and holds a large number of string objects, which persist through its life.

Reducing number of scanned objects should reduce GC time. I was wondering whether intern pool is excepted from garbage collection. There isn't anything to collect there anyway. If so, I could intern all these strings and speed up GC.

Comment: _Reducing number of scanned objects should reduce GC time_  - something to verify first. It's the references _to_ the strings that need to be scanned, no way to avoid that.  But as the CLR knows about the string pool, it might be a little faster.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Good remark, but see my test below. It seems that even though a string does not contain any references internally and could be skipped, the intern pool is needlessly scanned for references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a quick test and interning of strings does not seem to save them from scanning by GC. At least not in .NET 4.5 64 bit.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; ++i)
        {
            string s = i.ToString("X");
            string.Intern(s);
        }
        GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        long t1 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        long t2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        Console.WriteLine((double)(t2 - t1) / Stopwatch.Frequency);
    }
}
```

This benchmark returns 0.23s on an i5 3570k. If the strings are put into an array instead of interning, it returns 0.26s. If the strings are interned and created via `(i % 10).ToString()`, i.e. there's a small number of different instances, the benchmark returns microseconds.

So sadly this is not a way to bypass garbage collection. I think C# should have some way of marking strings as persistent and stop the runtime wasting time on scanning them.

Answer (score 4):

> If you are trying to reduce the total amount of memory your
>   application allocates, keep in mind that interning a string has two
>   unwanted side effects. **First, the memory allocated for interned String
>   objects is not likely be released until the common language runtime
>   (CLR) terminates.** The reason is that the CLR's reference to the
>   interned String object can persist after your application, or even
>   your application domain, terminates. Second, to intern a string, you
>   must first create the string. The memory used by the String object
>   must still be allocated, even though the memory will eventually be
>   garbage collected.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern(v=vs.110).aspx

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Both those side effects are minor. @kaalus already stated "which persist through its life", the extra GC is a one time burden.

Comment: I am not trying to reduce memory usage, I am trying to reduce GC Gen2 time

Comment: @kaalus And the bold statement in my answer indicates that interned strings are not garbage collected.

Comment: @DanielMann I know the memory is not going to be released. What I am asking is whether the memory is scanned by the collector at every collection.