# .NET/mono const dictionary with million values for application lifetime

Tags: c#, caching, dictionary, mono, garbage-collection

In my application it would be very useful to keep some values during whole application life time in a large dictionary. The number of keys is about 700 000. I did some research and testing and it looks like I hit the limits of garbage collector performance on mono 3.2.8 because even the existence of (unused) large dictionary slows down whole application significantly (without any reads from dictionary)

It would be most convenient to keep objects directly in a dictionary. The memory usage is not an issue, currently it uses about 1.5G memory and it is acceptable, however even twice as much would be still ok.

I've tried storing data in file and keep only indices in memory. It reduces slow down but is still not satisfactory.

Is there any way to tell the GC to 'freeze' my dictionary and all of its objects? Because the flow is very simple and such optimization would help a lot:
- initialize dictionary from file
- perform only reads within next couple of hours
- shut down

So after initialization I would like to tel GC 'just please ignore all those 700 000 objects because I *know* they will live untouched until end of application'.

i would be very grateful for any advises. I can use external libraries but not services, e.g. installing memcache is not an option.

Comment: Related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779141/are-interned-strings-excepted-from-garbage-collection-in-net

Comment: I am sure because it is enough to initialize that dictionary and make no use of it and the application 'slows down' meaning it is 2 times slower. There are many steps and I measure times for all of them. The 'slow down' is equal for all steps even those totally not related to the mentioned dictionary.